# Any idea to obtain object distance or size from Velodyne point cloud?

Tags: ros, vlp16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working on VLP 16 velodyne data and I would like to detect the size of an object from the point cloud. I can calculate the size of the object if I obtain the distance and vice versa using simple trigonometry (since angular resolution is known). Since, lidars are laser beams, I am curious if ROS provides access to ToF values of the laser beams so that I can calculate distance from it? Or is there any better way to detect the size of an object or its distance from the lidar point cloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227434/any-idea-to-obtain-object-distance-or-size-from-velodyne-point-cloud?/) by [krishnaece1505](https://answers.ros.org/users/25947/krishnaece1505/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `velodyne_points` point cloud is a 3D representation in units of meters (the ROS standard). The trigonometry is been done by the `velodyne_pointcloud` package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0